# Creating partition from a start point till the end of the disk using parted

Tags: linux, filesystems, partition, parted

This is my partition table :

```
Model: ATA Hitachi HTS54757 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 750GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
 1      17.4kB  134MB   134MB                Mi                    msftres
 2      135MB   86.2GB  86.1GB  ntfs         Ba
 3      86.2GB  86.5GB  315MB   ntfs         Ba                    hidden
 4      86.5GB  86.6GB  105MB   fat16        EFI System Partition  boot
 5      86.6GB  86.8GB  210MB   fat16
 9      86.8GB  129GB   42.6GB                                     lvm
 6      129GB   236GB   107GB   ntfs
 7      236GB   343GB   107GB   ntfs
```

I want to create a last partition till the end of the disk to be like this :

```
8      343GB   750GB   407GB   ntfs
```

How to achieve this in case if i didn't know where to stop, i want to till parted that i want to make a partition from `343GB` till the end of the disk, how to do so ?

I'm using parted 3.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending in your `parted` version you can define sizes in percentage. End of your last partition is at 100%.

Comment: I'v edited my question. I'm using Parted 3.1

Comment: @RafaelAdel I could not find hard evendence when this possibility appeared, but it is definitively available at least since version 1.8.1.